# How to interpret path coefficients in path analysis

Tags: r, r-lavaan, semplot

I am trying to come up with a path analysis diagram using lavaan and semPlot.

1) Does anybody know how to interpret the path coefficients, especially those that does not originate anywhere but points to themselves, for eg. the coefficient 1.00 pointing to "DW", coefficient 0.61 pointing to "ANTS" and coefficient 0.92 pointing to "RH"?

2) Any idea how I can customise the graphics in the diagram, like add a title or make the box bigger? I was referring to this site (http://sachaepskamp.com/documentation/semPlot/semPaths.html), but it does not show any example of adding titles and I've been trying out different codes with no success.

3) What information should I present? Is it sufficient to show the p-values of all the pathways and indicate which is significant? Thank you!

## Specify Model for ants diversity

```
Model.ants<-'Ants~AGB+Max.Temp+Min.RH+Deadwood.quantity
Deadwood.quantity~AGB
Max.Temp~AGB
Min.RH~AGB
Max.Temp~~Min.RH'
```

## Results

```
Result.ants<-sem(Model.ants,data=combined)
Fit.ants<-cfa(Model.ants,data=combined)
summary (Result.ants,standardized=TRUE,fit.measures=TRUE,rsq=TRUE,
modindices=TRUE)
```

## Plot path

```
semPaths(Result.ants,"std",intercept=FALSE,edge.label.cex=0.8, 
curvePivot = TRUE,layout = "spring",
nodeLabels = c("ANT","DW","Temp","RH","AGB"),title = TRUE)
```

[Path Analysis Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hrdad.jpg)

Comment: Regarding interpretation and presentation, [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) would likely be a more suitable forum to ask. As for customizing graphics, you'll be much more likely to receive an answer if you give a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Noted, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Please refere to to [semPlot: Unified visualizations of Structural
   Equation Models](http://www.sachaepskamp.com/files/semPlot.pdf):

> - Directed edges indicate   linear regression parameters
> - Bidirectional edges indicate (co)variances
> - (Residual) variances can be indicated in (...) Double headed selfloops (RAM style).

2. You can add title to a chart by calling `title` function and change size of element by assignment the argument `sizeMan` in `semPaths`:

   ```
   semPaths(fit, "std", layout = "circle", sizeMan = 2)
   title("My Paths")
   ```
3. You should presents all the model paraments (regression coefficients, variances, covariances etc.) moreover "*p* < 0.05 then the effect is significat" does not work for SEM generally.

Comment: Thank you! This is very useful indeed!